# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_cache" ERROR Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

Following a migration of my Symfony from 4.2 to 4.4
I got this error when I performed my evolution. But all this work long before

version :
Php 7.3.19

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "doctrine_cache" (in "/var/www/intranet/config/packages/doctrine_cache.yaml"). Looked for namespace "doctrine_cache", found ""framework", "sensio_framework_extra", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "security", "swiftmailer", "twig", "monolog", "knp_paginator"".  in /var/www/intranet/vendor/symfony/config/Loader/FileLoader.php on line 180
```

Content of composer.json

```
{
"type": "project",
"license": "proprietary",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.7",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.10",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "^3.0",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.20",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
    "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
    "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/property-access": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/property-info": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.1",
    "symfony/templating": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/css-selector": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^6.1",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.4.*"
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "*": "dist"
    },
    "sort-packages": true
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"replace": {
    "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
},
"scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "require": "4.4.*"
    }
}
```

the bundle :

return [
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],

```
Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
Knp\Bundle\PaginatorBundle\KnpPaginatorBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

];

What I tried was to add a Cache doctrine line in the Bundle but that caused an error that told me that I didn't have the class at the Kermel level.

So I write this message to ask for help :)

Comment: You can try editing your doctrine.yml file and simply commenting out the doctrine_cache section.  Symfony has replace Doctrine's caching stuff with their own cache pools though I'm not sure when all that happened.  Assuming that removing the doctrine_cache section fixes the error then you cam look at the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers) to see how to add caching back in if desired.

Comment: I carried out this method but it does not work but I solved the problem by upgrading the Composer version to 2 and after I `php composer recipes:install --force -v && 
php composer  install
 `